# javascript events not working with dynamic content added with json

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, dom

I'm stuck with a situation where my DOM elements are generated dynamically based on `$.getJSON` and Javascript functions for this elements are not working. I'll post some general idea on my code because I'm looking just an direction of what should I do in this situation.

`site.js` contains general features like

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.element').on('click', function() {
        $(this).toggleClass('active');
    });

    $(".slider").slider({
        // some slider UI code...
    });
});
```

After that:

```
$.getJSON('json/questions.json', function (data) {
    // generating some DOM elements...
});
```

I have also tried to wrap all site.js content into function `refresh_scripts()` and call it after `$.getJSON()` but nothing seems to be working.

Comment: More simpler, just put your slider events and click events inside the success function with the use of `.unbind()` method

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Firstly you need to use a delegated event handler to catch events on dynamically appended elements. Then you can call the `.slider()` method again within the success handler function to instantiate the plugin on the newly appended content. Try this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#parentElement').on('click', '.element', function() {
        $(this).toggleClass('active');
    });

    var sliderOptions = { /* slider options here */ };
    $(".slider").slider(sliderOptions);

    $.getJSON('json/questions.json', function(data) {
        // generating some DOM elements...
        $('#parentElement .slider').slider(sliderOptions);
    });
});
```

Comment: Magic. It works :) Thanks a lot Rory, really appreciate your answer and edits

Answer (score 1):

Instead of calling `on` directly on the element, call it on a parent that isn't dynamically added and then use the optional `selector` parameter to narrow it to the element.

```
$('.parent').on('click', '.element', () => {
    // do something
});
```

The difference between this and:

```
$('.element').on('click', () => {});
```

is with `$('.element').on()`, you're only applying the listener to the elements that are currently in that set. If it's added after, it won't be there.

Applying it to `$(.parent)`, that parent is always there, and will then filter it to all of it's children, regardless when they're added.

Comment: Thank you. It works for the click elements and you provide an useful information on how I should plan elements generation with parent elements.

Answer (score 1):

the easiest way is to add this after you add/generate your DOM

```
$('script[src="site.js"]').remove();
$('head').append('<script src="site.js"></script>');
```

of course your js function that generates DOM needs to be on another file than your site.js